# Azure usage costs - confused

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, billing

This is my azure payasyougo usage cost for this month.

[image]

I'm struggling to understand why I would be charged for a Standard Medium App Service, I would of thought that it would be included in the compute hours? I have only one Cloud Service running and this seems a bit steep for a cloud service that is not doing much...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Billing questions are off-topic. That said, I don't actually understand your question. What do you mean by your app service being included in compute hours?

Comment: Please check the details of consumption (Simply click on this box and it will open a new blade with detailed consumption). I am pretty sure that there's a website (web app) running somewhere in your Azure Subscription that you're not aware of. Other alternative would be to download usage report from https://account.windowsazure.com.

Comment: @DavidMakogon if billing topics are off topic, where does one go to get a general question answered?  I'm confused as to what is Standard Medium App Service hours relates to. I have only Large cloud service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While pricing is off-topic, I think I can answer this from a general operational angle (even though this will likely be closed since it's not programming-related).

As your graphic shows, you are consuming resources for different services. Compute-hours equates to your virtual machines that you've deployed, and you're consuming those resources whether you're using 0% or 100% CPU / memory / network, whether you've deployed code or not. They are allocated and, as far as Azure is concerned, deployed for your use, no matter what you're doing (or not doing) with them.

When you created your App Service, that was yet-another set of resources deployed. And another set of resource-hours you're consuming (again, whether you use 0% or 100% is irrelevant).

Same thing would happen if you created a database instance or any other Azure service: You'd pay in whatever way is described for that particular service. And each service has its own specific cost which is described in detail in Azure's pricing page.

There's no nesting of separate services. In your specific case: there's no concept of creating an App Service inside a Virtual Machine (nor is there any hint of that anywhere). They are two separate services.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up David. There was a app service that was created and not used and I thought that it was related to the cloud service...

Answer (score -1):

Computer covers only Virtual Machines and Cloud Services.  Pricing can be found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

App Services are "special", while they internally use compute resources behind the scenes, they are charged based on the tier of performance and SLA you want to achieve.  Pricing for them can be found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

You will notice that there is a PREMIUM price for the same level of service on App Services.  The theory is that the App Service stack is providing more managed value and thus worth more.  For my use cases I have not found this to be the case and instead choose to run our environments under the PaaS VM / Cloud Service stacks.

Comment: This is a billing question, which is already off-topic. Adding your own spin / opinion on which environment to use is not helpful. Further, app services aren't "special" when it comes to billing - they're billed per time deployed, just like virtual machines and cloud services.